# How to setup local version control with GitExtensions?

Tags: git, git-extensions

So I'm new to version control, but have read the documentation of GitExtensions but it was of limited help because it focused on dealing with remote repositories.

What I need is to have version control for my local projects. I have Android and Visual Studio projects I work on as the only developer, so the source is all on my local computer. I do not want to put the source up in GitHub or anywhere on the internet yet. For now I just want to setup and use the version control local on my own PC.

I have GitExtensions installed, and created a local repository at `C:\Programs\gitrepos\projectname\` My code is at `C:\Projects\projectname\`.

My first problem is that I do not understand how to specify the location of my source files?! I see setting remote source, but I am not using remote sources. Did I do this wrong? Should the repository be in the same folder as my source files? Nothing I've found thus far explains how git or gitextensions works when dealing with local-only source that you want to version control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A git repository works from a certain root directory downwards. This root directory will contain a folder named `.git`. All the information of your versioning history is saved in **that one folder**

If you want to version specific files, they must be in your "repository". This means they have to be in or below the folder that contains the `.git` folder.

In other words, your last idea is correct and you should have created the repository at `C:\Projects\projectname`

Comment: You can tell git to look somewhere else for the repository by setting the `GIT_DIR` environment variable. I don't know if GitExtensions can handle that setup though.

Comment: @wumpus setting the git directory in another folder is for special cases and in it's case should be avoided, especially for a beginner. So, indeed, the git repository must be created in the source folder.